# Display Users in Admin Panel Using Laravel and VueJS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

I am creating an Admin panel using Laravel which can manage all the users using VueJS.

**UserController.php**

```
public function show(User $user)
    {

        $user = User::all();
        return UsereResource($user);
    }
```

**UserResource.php**

```
public function toArray($request)
{

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
    ];
}
```

**UserVue.js**

```
    <template>
        <div id="app">
            <p class="border p-3" v-for="user in users">
                {{ user.name }}
                <button 
                    type="button" 
                    @click="deleteUser(user.id)" 
                    class="p-1 mx-3 float-right btn btn-danger"
                >
                    Delete
                </button>
            </p>
            <div>
                <button 
                    v-if="next" 
                    type="button" 
                    @click="navigate(next)" 
                    class="m-3 btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Next
                </button>
                <button 
                    v-if="prev" 
                    type="button" 
                    @click="navigate(prev)" 
                    class="m-3 btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Previous
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      mounted() {
        this.getUsers();
      },
      data() {
        return {
          users: {},
          next: null,
          prev: null
        };
      },
      methods: {
        getUsers(address) {
          axios.get(address ? address : "/api/users").then(response => {
            this.users = response.data.data;
            this.prev = response.data.links.prev;
            this.next = response.data.links.next;
          });
        },
        deleteUser(id) {
          axios.delete("/api/users/" + id).then(response => this.getUsers())
        },
        navigate(address) {
          this.getUsers(address)
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

**api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');
```

web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin/{any}', 'AdminController@index')->where('any', '.*');
Route::get('/user/{any}', 'UserController@index')->where('any', '.*');
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('/users', 'UserController@store');
```

I keep getting the error **app.js:267 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users 401 (Unauthorized)**

In console it says

```
{message: "Unauthenticated."}
message: "Unauthenticated."
```

I have been stuck at this forever and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: this is because you haven't passed authentication token in api call header in your vuejs file

Comment: This middleware "auth:api" has an authenticating mechanism, you can disable if you don't need it and test again. if you need an authenticating mechanism you must provide authorization token in vuejs and send the request.